# Game Timer using NSDate with NSTimer? swift

Tags: swift, timer, nsdate, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I want to start a timer at a specific date and time, then use that start time as a game timer for the rest of the game. Using "timeIntervalSinceDate" will give me seconds but then trying to get the seconds to display on the gameTimerLabel won't work. I might be coming at this the wrong way. Any advice is welcome.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()


    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
    let dateAsString1 = "Fri, 1 April 2016 11:30:00 MST"
    let date1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateAsString1)!
    var currentTime = NSDate()
   var counter = 0
    gameTimerLabel.text = String(counter)
    gameTimerLabel.text = counter  //<- Error:Cannot assign value to type 'Int' to type 'String?'
    counter = date1.timeIntervalSinceDate(currentTime)  //<- Error:Cannot assign value of type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'Double') to type 'Int'

}
```

Comment: You need to convert your time interval to string

Comment: counter should be declared as Double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things here

First, when you declare counter, it's inferred to be of type Int

```
var counter = 0
```

You can declare it as a double by adding a .0 or specifying it's type:

```
var counter: NSTimeInternval = 0.0
```

Next, you can use string interoperability to display the count variable in a string, like this:

```
gameTimerLabel.text = "\(counter)"
```

Here's an example view controller using an NSTimer as a counter, it counts in seconds:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

// Setup a timer and a counter for use
var timer   = NSTimer()
var counter : NSTimeInterval = 0

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

// Invalidest the timer, resets the counter and udpates the label
@IBAction func resetTimer(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Invalidate the timer, reset the label.
    self.timer.invalidate()
    self.label.text = ""
    self.counter    = 0
}

// A button that when pressed starts and stops the timer
// There's no pause/resume, so it's invalidated & created again
// But the counter value reamins the same
@IBAction func timerBttnTouched(sender: AnyObject) {

    if self.timer.valid {

        self.timer.invalidate()

    } else {

        self.setupTimer()
    }
}

// Does the actual counting everytime the timer calls this method
func timerFired() {

    self.counter += 1
    self.label.text = "\(self.counter)"
}

// Setups a timer, adds it to the run loop and specifies what method should fire when the timer fires
func setupTimer() {

    // Setupt the timer, this will call the timerFired method every second
    self.timer = NSTimer(
        timeInterval: 1,
        target: self,
        selector: #selector(self.timerFired),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)

    // Add the timer to the run loop
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(
        self.timer,
        forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
}
}
```

An important thing to note when using timers is they may not always be called *exactly* when you need them to, this should be taken into account according to your desired precision when using a timer.

As discussed in comments, here's the solution using a timer to fire a method that compares two dates and uses a NSDateComponentsFormatter to generate a string for display. The initial date is generated in viewDidLoad but can be created anywhere:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

// Setup a timer and a counter for use
var timer   = NSTimer()
var counter : NSTimeInterval = 0

var startDate: NSDate?

override func viewDidLoad() {

    // Set the initial date
    self.startDate = NSDate()
}

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

// Invalidest the timer, resets the counter and udpates the label
@IBAction func resetTimer(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Invalidate the timer, reset the label.
    self.timer.invalidate()
    self.label.text = ""
    self.counter    = 0
}

// A button that when pressed starts and stops the timer
// There's no pause/resume, so it's invalidated & created again
// But the counter value reamins the same
@IBAction func timerBttnTouched(sender: AnyObject) {

    if self.timer.valid {

        self.timer.invalidate()

    } else {

        self.setupTimer()
    }
}

// Does the actual counting everytime the timer calls this method
func timerFired() {

    let now = NSDate()
    let difference = now.timeIntervalSinceDate(self.startDate!)

    // Format the difference for display
    // For example, minutes & seconds
    let dateComponentsFormatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
    dateComponentsFormatter.stringFromTimeInterval(difference)

    self.label.text = dateComponentsFormatter.stringFromTimeInterval(difference)
}

// Setups a timer, adds it to the run loop and specifies what method should fire when the timer fires
func setupTimer() {

    // Setupt the timer, this will call the timerFired method every second
    self.timer = NSTimer(
        timeInterval: 1,
        target: self,
        selector: #selector(self.timerFired),
        userInfo: nil,
        repeats: true)

    // Add the timer to the run loop
    NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(
        self.timer,
        forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
}
}
```

Comment: I've add those changes. It now displays. How would I get it to count? or update the time to count properly?

Comment: For that you should use an NSTimer, let me give you an alternative in the answer in a few moments.

Comment: @Ring-Jarvi I've updated my answer with an alternative approach using a timer.

Comment: Your precision comment is the reason I was trying to build a timer from NSDate. This timer starts as soon as the app starts correct? I was trying to set it off of a date and time.

Comment: No, this starts on button press.

Comment: I know that, my original question was how to start a timer from NSDate

Comment: That is the first part of my answer - you already have the concept

Comment: Or use a timer for continuous date comparison and UI updating

Comment: @Ring-Jarvi I have added an example using a timer to compare dates into the answer.

Comment: I have been working with your code but have been getting   Error Code: Thread 1:signal SIGABRT.  I converted the start date I wanted from a string to NSDate and when I run the code I get this error. I've done research and found nothing helpful. Thoughts?

Comment: Usually Xcode highlights the line where the error is, on SO it's good to keep ?s on one topic, I would just make sure you're converting the date properly and not force unwrapping it. Do some tests in playground to make sure you have the format correct.